# Free hotkeys I can customize in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, hotkeys

What key combinations is suggested for custom key bindings in for example AutoHotkey? I mean what keys are not allready hooked up to vital features per default in Windows 7? I have loads of things I need to create custon hotkeys for on a company with many users and I dont want to remove/override mappings that people are allready using but Im not being aware of. Is there any central place in Windows to overview all keybindings? It would be great if perhaps all Windowskey+XXX was customizable globally on Windows somehow, like in a pc-game.

Comment: There is an extensive list of the [most common shotcuts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_keyboard_shortcuts) over at Wikipedia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following page lists all hotkeys employed by Windows 7:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Keyboard-shortcuts

You are probably most interested in the section titled "Windows logo key keyboard shortcuts".

Comment: I believe Andreas is asking for some way to see all current mappings for any given user/system in order to see current custom mappings.

Answer (score 0):

It does not appear there is a single location where all currently mapped hotkeys are listed or stored.

See this post for a way to create a vb script that can parse locations for links with associated hotkeys. You can probably go beyond what was suggested here and script the whole thing, reporting to a central location per machine.

http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/19797-45-custom-shortcut-keys-list-remove

Another result found in google appeared to offer a similar script, but the page 404'd.